# ViewPager calling multiple times -- Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am doing graph using `onDraw()` method. I have four different Fragments which contains different graphs. I used `ViewPager` to show the graph in swipe model.

When I call `viewPager.getCount()` it's getting called multiple times. Later I found that the `onDraw()` method was calling each time I touched the screen or when I swipe the fragment. I really wondered why the Fragment is called several times while using `ViewPager`. I didn't get any proper solution for this, can anyone guide me how to restrict multiple calling of `getCount()` or calling Fragment when doing a swipe.

Comment: View pager is always looks/load 2 pages at a time, i.e, when you focuses first page the second page is also loads. So when you need to load fragment only one at a time, then add a page listener and add a switch/if-else condition with page position.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do you have any sample for this please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,
 Add a `mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageLitsener);`

And 
 define as,

```
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mPageLitsener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            ((FirstFragment)mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(0)).onUpdate();
            break;

            case 1:
            ((SecondFragment)mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(1)).onUpdate();
            break;

            case 2:
            ((ThirdFragment)mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(2)).onUpdate();
            break;

            default:
            ((FirstFragment)mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(0)).onUpdate();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
};
```

Then call a public method inside of Fragment (i.e, `onUpdate()`), and define that as what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, im implementing the code which you sent. I will accept your answer if it works fine. Thanks again.